# Dynamic reduction of elements in vector

Tags: algorithm, matlab, vector, dynamic, reduction

I have a vector which contains several different values, where all of them are between 0 and 1.

I have also two different values, called min and max, that represent the minimum and maximum values; this two values may change in time.

I would reduce dynamically the dimension of a vector, which values must be included within the gap described by min and max.

For example,
at time t=1 I have that vector:

```
 a=[0.5,0.2,0.6,0.3,0.2187,0.8798,0.5432,0.3563,0.3981,0.7845];
 min=0.3;
 max=0.7;
```

given vector a, and the two values (min and max), the  new vector: a_new,

should be:

```
 a_new=[0.5,0.6,0.3,0.5432,0.3563,0.3981];
```

this due to the fact that the `min` and `max` values decide which is the bound such that a new vector, starting from the original is defined.

Answer (score 3):

**Code solution**

If you just want to generate a new vector given the old one, use the following syntax:

```
a_new = a(a>=min & a<=max);
```

If you also want to calculate the positions of each the deleted and non deleted values, use MATLAB's find function:

```
nonDeleteIndices = find(a>=min & a<=max);
deletedIndices= find(a<min | a>max);
```

---

**Result**

```
a_new =

0.5000    0.6000    0.3000    0.5432    0.3563    0.3981


nonDeletedIndices=

 1     3     4     7     8     9


 deletedIndices=

 2     5     6     10
```

---

**Suggestion**

I suggest using different variable names other than min and max - such as minVal and maxVal. There are already MATLAB functions with these names and you don't want to override them.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I would know if is possible to know the position within the vector about the deleted elements. it is possible?

Comment: @Chask yes, it is possible, I modified my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks, just last question, the indices in output that I need, are the indices of the deleted elements for example with respect to my first question : 
indices= [ 2 5 6 10]